# Sequelize does not see foreign key when creating child entity

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

Please help solve the problem. there are department and employee models

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
var Department = sequelize.define('Department', {
name: DataTypes.STRING,
description: DataTypes.STRING
});

Department.associate = function(models) {
Department.hasMany(models.employee);
};

return Department;
};


module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
var Employee = sequelize.define('Employee', {
name: DataTypes.STRING,
age: DataTypes.INTEGER,
depart: DataTypes.STRING
});

Employee.associate = function (models) {
Employee.belongsTo(models.department, {
  foreignKey: {
    allowNull: false
  }
});
};


return Employee;
};
```

Associations are also written there that one department can have several employs, one employ has only one department.

further in the migration I add DepartmentId

```
module.exports = {
up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
return queryInterface.createTable("Employees", {
  id: {
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  age: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  },
  depart: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  createdAt: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.DATE
  },
  updatedAt: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.DATE
  },
  DepartmentId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: 'Departments',
      key: 'id'
    }
  }
 });
 },
 down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
 return queryInterface.dropTable("Employees");
 }
 };
```

further in the controller, I call the function, which should create in my database the emails with DepartmentId

```
module.exports.createEmployee = async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body) {
    return res.status(400).json({ massage: "Employee body is required" 
});
  }
 try {
    const employee = await Employee.create({
      name: req.body.name,
      age: req.body.age,
      depart: req.body.depart,
      DepartmentId: req.body.DepartmentId
    });
```

I'm sending a request through Postman

{ "name": "teqwest1", "age": "121", "depart": "qwew1qweqweqe", "DepartmentID" : "1" }

leading to an error

original:
   { error: null value in column "DepartmentId" violates not-null constraint
       at Connection.parseE (/home/vitalik/node/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:604:11)
       at Connection.parseMessage (/home/vitalik/node/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:401:19)
       at Socket. (/home/vitalik/node/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:121:22)
       at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
       at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
     name: 'error',
     length: 280,
     severity: 'ERROR',
     code: '23502',
     detail:
      'Failing row contains (62, teqwest1, 121, qwew1qweqweqe, 2019-10-11 14:51:37.856+00, 2019-10-11 14:51:37.856+00, null).',
     hint: undefined,
     position: undefined,
     internalPosition: undefined,
     internalQuery: undefined,
     where: undefined,
     schema: 'public',
     table: 'Employees',
     column: 'DepartmentId',
     dataType: undefined,
     constraint: undefined,
     file: 'execMain.c',
     line: '2017',
     routine: 'ExecConstraints',
     sql:
      'INSERT INTO "Employees" ("id","name","age","depart","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5) RETURNING *;',
     parameters:
      [ 'teqwest1',
        '121',
        'qwew1qweqweqe',
        '2019-10-11 14:51:37.856 +00:00',
        '2019-10-11 14:51:37.856 +00:00' ] },
  sql:
   'INSERT INTO "Employees" ("id","name","age","depart","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5) RETURNING *;',
  parameters:
   [ 'teqwest1',
     '121',
     'qwew1qweqweqe',
     '2019-10-11 14:51:37.856 +00:00',
     '2019-10-11 14:51:37.856 +00:00' ] }

Stack:

Nodejs

Express

Postgres

Sequelize

How to solve this problem, what would be created in a database that has a foreign key DepartmentId?

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Department = sequelize.define('Department', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.STRING
  });

  Department.associate = (models) => {
    models.Department.hasMany(models.Employee);
  };

  return Department;
};


module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Employee = sequelize.define('Employee', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    age: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  });

  Employee.associate = (models) => {
    models.Employee.belongsTo(models.Department, {
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'depart',
        allowNull: false
      }
    });
  };

  return Employee;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I made the changes you proposed, but unfortunately the error remained the same. For information, I will provide the full text of the error from CLI